# How can I partially remesh my model or get a similar effect?

Tags: 3d, blender, mesh, modeling

I have came back to using blender recently, as my motivation to improve my modeling skills returned to me.
So i have modeled this base for a dimetrodon mesh from simply placing UV spheres, and slightly sculpting them. The problem is, I want to remesh this model so it becomes one solid mesh with a similar levels of detail.

When I just use the "remesh" option, it either makes my model ultra detailic, making my PC to choke to it's death, or makes the whole model fine, but making thinner structures like sail bones, or fingers to disappear.
Is there any possibility so I could partially remesh the model, and leave the sailbones and feets on higher lvl of detail? I will upload the pictures of how does it look before and after remesh.
I'd be much grateful for a reliable answer as this was the problem that made me leave the blender last time, and I'd love to continue with upgrading my modelling skills :(

([before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOAfp.png)
([after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYjSw.png)

Comment: You should probably ask your question on [blender stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/), it seems way more active than stackoverflow for blender related questions. Also found that : [How to remesh model without losing details?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256789/how-to-remesh-model-without-losing-details) which seems pretty similar to your problem.

Comment: Welcome! Adding to what@Poulpynator said, this sounds off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please kindly read [this Help Center page](/help/on-topic) to learn what's on-topic here :)